# Invalid syntax error in python program which tries to figure out an IP

Tags: python, ip, ip-address

I have no experience whatsoever in coding but wanted to get this code snippet here working:

```
import re
import sys
import json
import GeoIP
import urllib
import string
import requests

gi = GeoIP.open("GeoLiteCity.dat",GeoIP.GEOIP STANDARD)
r = requests.get('http://lichess.org/stream', stream=True)

buff = ''
pattern = re.compile(sys.argv[1] + '.{30}')
for content in r.iter content():
    if content:
        buff = buff + content
        if len(buff) > 1000:
            result keys = re.findall(pattern, buff)
            for el in result keys:
                result = string.split(el)
                print result[0], result[1], result[2][:-8], gi.record by addr(result[2][:-8])['country name'],
                gi.record by addr(result[2][:-8])['region name'], gi.record by addr(result[2][:-8])['city'] 
            buff = buff[-30:]
```

the compiler tells me there is invalid syntax in line 9, where it says STANDARD.

I looked the code up to find out the IP adress of a user based on the ID of a game on a chess site called lichess.org. I sort of expect some changes will be necessary given the fact that this code was posted 7 years ago and lichess changed certain things.

The OP of the thread where I found this additionally gave this advice:

> usage: getip.py owlc08je

> where getip.py your script name, "owlc08je" -id of game. If someone making move in this game his ip, country and city print out to the console.

However, it does not work.

Thanks in advance

Edited code with underscores and changes:

```
import re
import sys
import json
import GeoIP
import urllib
import string
import requests

gi = GeoIP.open("GeoLiteCity.dat",GeoIP.GEOIP_STANDARD)
r = requests.get('http://lichess.org/stream', stream=True)

buff = ''
pattern = re.compile(sys.argv[1] + '.{30}')
for content in r.iter_content():
    if content:
        buff = buff + content
        if len(buff) > 1000:
            result_keys = re.findall(pattern, buff)
            for el in result_keys:
                result = string.split(el)
                print(result[0], result[1], result[2][:-8], gi.record_by_addr(result[2][:-8])['country name'],
    gi.record by addr(result[2][:-8])['region name'], gi.record by addr(result[2][:-8])['city'])
            buff = buff[-30:]
```

Comment: `GeoIP.GEOIP STANDARD` indeed is invalid syntax. If you don't know about python syntax check the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: ok I believe, I might have understood where the problem lays: the post I copy&pasted replaced all spaces with underscores. while converting them back, some correctly placed underscores might have been accidentally deleted

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing an underscore between GEOIP and STANDARD.

Replacing Line 9 with this should probably solve the issue:

```
gi = GeoIP.open("GeoLiteCity.dat",GeoIP.GEOIP_STANDARD)
```

EDIT:

As mentioned in one of the comments, if there are other places where underscores have been left out; that should solve the issue.

Comment: Yes thanks for the advice, I realized it just now and changed all the apparently missing underscores, but I still get an error: at line 21 on `['country name']`. The syntax error arrow is pointing to the whitespace. Switching it to an underscore does not solve the issue. What is wrong there?

Comment: What version of python are you using? Try wrapping the print statement in brackets if you have python 3.x. For eg. print(result[0]......[:-8]['city'])

Comment: ok, I've done that but then it gave me an invalid syntax error on "by", so I added some underscores on both sides and after that it said there is a syntax error on the last square bracket of city']).

Comment: Can you add the edited code in your question? It is not possible to understand otherwise where you have added underscores and where you haven't.

Comment: sure, done that (I deleted the underscores around by)

Comment: Add correct underscores to match record_by_addr in all instances, everything else seems ok at the moment

Comment: strange, suddenly the command line bombards me with errors on every line saying "Comand not found", and if I execute the python file the console only says it could not find the module GeoIP

Comment: You need to install the GeoIP package (https://pypi.org/project/GeoIP/). Its better to familiarise yourself with python packages and how to install them depending on the environment you are using.

Comment: I am using python 3.9.1 as far as I know. I looked up how to install geoip but pip installer doesn't seem to work either. I tried "pip help" and "python", but it does not even recognize these commands

Comment: If 'pip' and 'python' commands are not recognised, you should consider reinstalling python with proper configurations.

Comment: I reinstalled python, executed the command and still nothing happens: should I change directory or sth.?

Comment: ok I give up. the python command now works but pip cannot be downloaded because a proxyerror is breaking the connection. well doesn't work then